# How to display traffic data on MKMapView in iOS 6

Tags: maps, mkmapview, ios6-maps

Is there a way to display traffic data on MKMapView in iOS 6 without using 3rd-party API (no Google API)?

I thought since in iOS6 map data is provided by Apple, there should be a way to do this, but I can't seem to find the right API to do this.

Thanks,